# How to validate dropdown in angular 7 by template driven form

Tags: css, typescript, validation, angular8

Tried to validate dropdown select box but not working. May be css issue? So How to validate it. If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-template-driven-form-validation-qxecdm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html:

```
<div class="form-group col">
    <select id="inputState" #state="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.state" name="state" [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !state.valid }">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let optionName of formFields" value="{{optionName}}">{{optionName}}</option>
     </select> 
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
input[type=text].invalid-textbox,
select.invalid-textbox,
input[type=password].invalid-textbox {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ed5558;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working in the stackblitz. Template-driven forms use basic html validation so you had to add the required attribute. I also changed `!state.valid` to `state.invalid` in `[ngClass]`. The last thing I did was add an empty string for the value attribute and the selected attribute to initialize the ngModel state.

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="form-group col">
    <select id="inputState" #state="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.state" name="state"
        [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' : signUpForm.submitted && state.invalid }" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let optionName of formFields" [value]="optionName">{{optionName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
model: any = {
    state: ''
  };
```

This should respond now if a user deselects a state option and tries to submit it.

Comment: I updated the original answer again. The first answer introduced another issue but it was resolved. These changes should work for you.